# How to add x509_*(c.certificate) to the SELECT clause in my SQL query?

Tags: python, sql, json, python-3.x

I have a SQL query that I'm running through a python script. I've listed my working script and below. I'm trying to add x509_*(c.certificate) to the SELECT clause of my SQL query. I added the error below. I would greatly appreciate your help!

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "5:33pm", line 43, in <module> connect_to_db() File "5:33pm", line 32, in connect_to_db lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''',(domain_name,)) psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "x509_" does not exist LINE 2: x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_*(c.certificate) FROM c...
```

**SQL query**

```
'''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate),
x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_*(c.certificate) FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''',(domain_name,))
```